# How to get largest file from this python 3 code?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to find the largest file in a directory structure so I can then use that info to help in the creation of a database.

Here is the code:

```
import os
import datetime


def get_files(target):
# Get file size and modified time for all files from the target directory and down.
# Initialize files list
filelist = []
# Walk the directory structure
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(target):
    # Do not walk into directories that are mount points
    dirs[:] = filter(lambda dir: not os.path.ismount(os.path.join(root, dir)), dirs)
    for name in files:
        # Construct absolute path for files
        filename = os.path.join(root, name)
        # Test the path to account for broken symlinks
        if os.path.exists(filename):
            # File size information in bytes
            size = float(os.path.getsize(filename))
            # Get the modified time of the file
            #mtime = os.path.getmtime(filename)
            # Create a tuple of filename, size, and modified time
            construct = filename, size, #str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(mtime))
            # Add the tuple to the master filelist
            filelist.append(construct)
print(sorted([filelist]))
# with open("/home/dave/sizes.txt", 'w') as size_file:
#     contents = filelist.readline()


get_files("/home/dave/TL/case")
```

As you can see, I am a newbie and not sure how to pass the results of the function to a file.

My ultimate goal is just to find the largest file and it's size. It can go to a file or to stdout.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one verbose way to do it. First I am creating a list of File Name and File Size [tuples](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences). Then I am iterating through the list and saving the largest file Name and Size.

```
import os


fileSizeTupleList = []
largestSize = 0

for i in os.listdir(os.curdir):
    if os.path.isfile(i):
        fileSizeTupleList.append((i, os.path.getsize(i)))

for fileName, fileSize in fileSizeTupleList:
    if fileSize > largestSize:
        largestSize = fileSize
        largestFile = fileName

print(largestFile, largestSize)
```

Here is a recursive approach:

```
import os


fileSizeTupleList = []
largestSize = 0

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.curdir):
    for file in files:
        fileSizeTupleList.append((file, os.path.getsize(os.path.join(root, file))))

for fileName, fileSize in fileSizeTupleList:
    if fileSize > largestSize:
        largestSize = fileSize
        largestFile = fileName

print(largestFile, largestSize)
```

Comment: Hi Igor and thank you for the code. This works great for the current directory. As you can see from my code, I am needing to traverse a directory structure. Feel free to post up any changes that would allow that. I am going to also try to incorporate your code into mine and see what the results are.

Comment: @Dave It is my pleasure to help. See the update to my answer. Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Good news. Take a look at @Padraic's answer too. His is more compact and flexible though maybe bit harder to understand for beginner Pythonistas like us.

Comment: Yea I got lost at "generator function". I have SO much to learn. Will need to read up on that.

Answer (score 2):

Just make your function a  generator function and  call `max` using file size as the key with `itemgetter(1)`:

```
import os
def get_files(target):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(target):
        # Do not walk into directories that are mount points
        dirs[:] = filter(lambda d: not os.path.ismount(os.path.join(root, d)), dirs)
        for name in files:
            # Construct absolute path for files
            filename = os.path.join(root, name)
            # Test the path to account for broken symlinks
            if os.path.exists(filename):
                # File size information in bytes                  
                yield filename, os.path.getsize(filename)
```

That will allow you to reuse the function how ever you like:

```
In [5]: from operator import itemgetter

In [6]: max(get_files("."),key=itemgetter(1))
Out[6]: 
('./node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-parser/bg.gif',
 1277113)
```

If you wanted to sort the files by name alphabetically:

```
sorted(get_files("path"))
```

Sort by size:

```
 sorted(get_files("path"), key=itemgetter(1))
```